# Angular 2 : mutualise the call of an object from the server

Tags: javascript, mean-stack, angular2-services

Bonjour,

I created an angular application, but I did something dirty (because first it was not dirty, but growing my app, I realised that it was becoming dirty).

Basicly, I've a service called user.service.ts where I call my datebase to return me my User Object.

The thing is... I call the service, to get the SAME user in almost all the pages of my application.. And I would like to know how to call that once and for all, in the highest component ?

Thank you !

Comment: Why not cache it in your service (using a simple property)?

Comment: Hum could be a solution. I've many informations inside, do you think it will be okay for the user ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. In what way wouldn't that be okay?

Comment: Well, If I do that, I'll have to store a huge json object in the cache. It might be really heavy for the user browser, no ? Making my application heavy ?

Comment: Why is it huge (and how "huge" do you mean), isn't it user data? Do you have to fetch everything that it contains at the same time? In any case, it's got to be stored somewhere when your service returns it, so it shouldn't make much difference.

Comment: (Unrelated, but I'm assuming your service method is returning an Observable or something asynchronous. You'd then have to tap into it to cache the data once retrieved.)

Comment: Hum you're right, it should not make a big difference. I'll do like you said